# jQuery: ajax renderes row twice

Tags: jquery, ajax

this one is working:

```
setInterval(function () {
        var bodyCSS = "table > tbody > tr > td.left";
        $(bodyCSS).each(function(){
            if(!$(this).next().next().hasClass('body')){
                $(this).next().after("<td class = 'body'><i class = 'fa fa-plus-square-o'></i></td>");
            }
        });
    }, 500);
```

But this one is not working:

```
setInterval(function () {
        var bodyCSS = "table > tbody > tr > td.left";
        $(bodyCSS).each(function(){
            if(!$(this).next().next().hasClass('body')){
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        context: this,
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'https://peace-song.com/data.php',
                        data: {
                            "artist": $(this).next().html().split('-')[0],
                            "name": $(this).next().html().split('-')[1]
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            data = JSON.parse(data);
                            $(this).next().after("<td class = 'body'><i class = 'fa fa-plus-square-o'></i></td>");
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    }, 500);
```

By not working, I mean it is working for some time, but after rendering around 10 rows, two `<td class = 'body'>...` gets rendered in one line. Why?

[image]
I have a suspicion that it is due to `if(!$(this).next().next().hasClass('body')){...` not checking right. But why is it checking differently for each?

Comment: Why don't you work with indexes instead of .next().next()?

Comment: @Yuri, could you please give an example of index?

Comment: var cell = $(this);
var row = cell.parent();
var current_column = row.children().index(cell);
if(!row.find('td:nth-child('+(current_column+2)+')').hasClass('body')){....}

current_column+2 => your next().next()

Comment: At this moment, the idea is to stop rendering twice. Will index help me?

Comment: Can you provide a little html example of your table?

Comment: `var bodyCSS` is `Queen` in the picture. So, `next().next()` is `plus sign`. Now, if there is no `body` class, then put that `plus`. If not, then don't put. But it keeps putting it, despite `if(!$(this).next().next().hasClass('body')){...`.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
if($(this).next().next().next().hasClass('body')){
      $(this).next().next().next().remove();
}
```

Looks not good, but the unnecessary data removal guaranteed.

Any suggestions are welcomed.